# tikzcd downarrow aligned in one column

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd

I am trying to draw an `arrow[d]` that would depart directly from `C` straight to `Y` :

```
\documentclass{beamer}                                                                                
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] &  B +   &C  \arrow[d]\\
            &         &   Y
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

However, this yields in a lot of space between `+` and `C`:

[image]

Reducing the number of columns seems to solve this, but I cannot get the `arrow[d]` to depart from `C`. (It is instead departing from the `+` sign):

```
\documentclass{beamer}                                                                                
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] &  B +   C  \arrow[d]\\
            &            Y                                                                             
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How could I get `\arrow[d]` to depart from `C` straight to `Y` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a way to do the backing up in automated fashion, but for a single shot this seems easier.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3em]
A \arrow[r] &  B +{}   &[-3.8em] C  \arrow[d]\\
            &         &   Y
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say this is very pretty, but the following *more or less* works.

Note: `shift left` is used and not `shift right`, because the `left` or `right` qualifier is relative to the arrow direction—downwards here.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newlength{\myLen}
\newlength{\myLenii}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\myLenii}{$C$}
\settowidth{\myLen}{$B+C$}
\addtolength{\myLen}{-\myLenii}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] &  B + C  \arrow[d, shift left=0.5\myLen]\\
            &         \hspace*{\myLen}Y
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]